# Bootstrap css is not working in form validation

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here am validating a form fields. To get three text boxes in a same line I put three divs inside one `<div class="form-group">`.

When I click sign up with blank fields it gives proper error message then after if I enter any data in textbox am not getting green color right mark instead right mark with red color only when I fill all three text boxes it gives green color right mark. Can anyone suggest how to do proper alignment and proper messages?

```
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css"   rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/datepicker/css/datepicker.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Mine/css/MyCss.css"></link> 

        <form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="login.jsp">                         
<div class="form-group">                    
<label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Student Full Name</label>                     
<div class="col-xs-3">                  
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />                    
</div>          
<div class="col-xs-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="middleName" placeholder="Middle name" />               
</div>                      
<div class="col-xs-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />               
</div>
</div>                      

<div class="form-group">                    
<label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Parents Full Name</label>                     
<div class="col-xs-3">                  
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="First name" />                    
</div>          
<div class="col-xs-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="middleName" placeholder="Middle name" />               
</div>                      
<div class="col-xs-3">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />               
</div>
</div>                      

<div class="form-group">                    
<label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Phone</label>                     
<div class="col-xs-3">                  
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" />                  
</div>          
<label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Email</label>                     
<div class="col-xs-3">                  
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email" />                     
</div>
</div>  



                             <div class="form-group">                   
                                      <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Permanent</label>                       
                                      <div class="col-xs-3">                                                
                                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="presentaddress" /></textarea>
                                      </div>        
                                      <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Present</label>                     
                                      <div class="col-xs-3">                                                
                                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="presentaddress" /></textarea>
                                      </div>
                            </div>

                             <div class="form-group">                        
                                <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Date-of-birth</label>                     
                                <div class="col-xs-3 ">                                             
                                <div class="input-group input-append date" id="datePicker">
                                <input type="Text" class="form-control" name="dob" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon add-on"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                                </div>              
                                </div>  
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">                        
                            <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Class to join</label>                     
                            <div class="col-xs-3">                  
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="classtojoin" placeholder="Class to Join" />                   
                            </div>                      
                        </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-10 ">                                
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
                                </div>
                          </div>                            
                      </form>
    <script src="../Mine/scripts/MyScripts.js"></script>
            <!-- jQuery -->
            <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
            <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
            <script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
            <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
            <script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"  src="../dist/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>


$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#datePicker')
        .datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
        })
         .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'dob');
          }); 

    $('#fromdatePicker')
    .datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date field
       $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'fromyear');
    });

    $('#todatePicker')
    .datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(e) {
        // Revalidate the date field
       $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'toyear');
    });




    $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            firstName: {
               // container: '#firstNameMessage',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            lastName: {
                //container: '.lastNameMessage',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            middleName: {
                //container: '.middleNameMessage',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },

            studentusername: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentpassward: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        pattern: "/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{2})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/; ",
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    }
                }
             },
            gender: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The gender is required'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentplaceofbirth: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The place of birth is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentmothetongue: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The mother tongue is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentemailid: {
              validators: {
                  notEmpty: {
                      message: 'The email address is required'
                  },
                  emailAddress: {
                      message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                  }
              }
            },
            studentmobileno: {
             validators: {
                 notEmpty: {
                     message: 'The phone number is required'
                 },
                 regexp: {
                     message: 'The phone number can only contain the digits, spaces, -, (, ), + and .',
                     regexp: /^[0-9\s\-()+\.]+$/
                 }
             }
            },
            studentemgno: {
                 validators: {
                     notEmpty: {
                         message: 'The phone number is required'
                     },
                     regexp: {
                         message: 'The phone number can only contain the digits, spaces, -, (, ), + and .',
                         regexp: /^[0-9\s\-()+\.]+$/
                     }
                 }
               },
               studentpresentaddress: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The present address is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentpermanentaddress: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The  premanent address is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentbloodgroup: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The blood group is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentreligion: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The religion is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            studentcaste: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The caste is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
             dob: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The date is required'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                    }
                }
            }, 
            classtojoin: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The class to join is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }

        },
        studentnation: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The Nationality is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },

         fatherfirstname: {
                validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        },
        fatherlastname: {
            validators: {
            notEmpty: {
                message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
            }
        }
    },
    fathermiddlename: {
        validators: {
        notEmpty: {
            message: 'The middle name is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
},
        motherfirstname: {
         validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
    }
}
},
        motherlastname: {
        validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
},
        mothermiddlename: {
        validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        message: 'The middle name is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
},
        guardianfirstname: {
        validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        message: 'The first name is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
},
        guardianlastname: {
        validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        message: 'The last name is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
},
        guardianmiddlename: {
        validators: {
        notEmpty: {
        message: 'The middle name is required and cannot be empty'
        }
    }
},

        }

                });




});
```

Comment: You need to shorten your code or divide it so it will be possible to answer your question.

Comment: i got answer if i make unique identification of fields its working